# Google drive api 500 error in 80% of requests on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm using Drive API on Google app engine.
Application servers 7k request per day.

During last day number of errors from api increased to nearly 60%.

```
{ "code" : 500, "message" : null }
```

I use this code to initialize drive:

```
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        AppIdentityCredential credential =
                new AppIdentityCredential.Builder(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).build();
        GoogleClientRequestInitializer keyInitializer =
                new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer(Settings.API_KEY);
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                .setApplicationName(APP_NAME)
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(keyInitializer)
                .build();
        return service;
```

Does any one have same situation?
Are there any solutions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Have started working without any changes from my side.

Answer (score 1):

There are many bugs in Drive that can cause hard 500 errors, and also many transient internal scenarios (esp. timeouts) that can cause them. It's important that you do as much research as possible so you can distinguish between the two, since some are permanent whereas others may succeed after a backoff and retry.

In your case, I suspect you are tripping over the infrastructure issues that Google have confirmed have been affecting Drive (and perhaps other services) over the last few days. See https://plus.google.com/106160348960403302854/posts/CwH9SEDTQ4C

Comment: As an aside, be especially careful using the Drive client libraries. I suspect they do a backoff and retry on all 500 responses, which can sometimes loop forever in the case of hard error.